# Referencing multiple submit buttons in django

Tags: django

How would I call on the following multiple submit forms --

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="{{ email.id }}" value=" {{email}}"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

I want to do something like this --

```
if value = edit:
    do this

if value = delete:
    do this
```

How would I code this in the views.py file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Give the input types a name and look for them in your `request.POST` dictionary.

E.g.:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="{{ email.id }}" value=" {{email}}"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="_edit"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="_delete"></td>
</tr>
```

and in views.py something like

```
if request.POST:
    if '_edit' in request.POST:
         do_edit()
    elif '_delete' in request.POST:
         do_delete()
```

EDIT: Changed `d.has_key(k)` to `k in d` per Daniel's comment.  `has_key` is deprecated in python 3.0 and the in style is preferred as its more generic -- specifically `d.has_key(k)` fails if d isn't a dictionary, but `k in d` works for any `d` that's an iterable (e.g., dict, string, tuple, list, set).

Comment: `foo.has_key('bar')` has been spelled as `'bar' in foo` since Python 2.4.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks -- Edited with explanation for why `k in d` is preferred as it works for any d that's iterable.

Comment: Bear in mind that if there are multiple submit buttons in a form and the user presses Enter, then that'll automatically click whichever button comes first in the HTML.

Comment: @stevejalim - Yes if there are `<input type='text'>` fields and the user presses enter that by default the first input type=submit will be sent.  But you could use some javascript to disable this behavior.  E.g., http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/enter.html

Comment: This doesn't works for me working with crispy forms.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but for the record here is a solution using class-based views. It uses the same html as in dr jimbob's answer.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    form_class = MyForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if '_delete' in self.request.POST:
            # do delete
        elif '_edit' in self.request.POST:
            # do edit
```

Note the default behavior of `form_valid` is:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: I used ``if "key" in form.data: form.instance.field = special_value``

Answer (score 5):

You would need to give the submit buttons a name attribute, say "action" for example, then you could reference them in the request.POST collection:

```
def my_view(request):
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if action == 'Edit':
        #do edit
    else:
        # do delete
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Will break after title change, e.g. internationalization. Will work with `<button>`s though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="{{ email.id }}" value=" {{email}}"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="submit"> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit"> </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

views.py will be -

```
def our_view(request):
    if request.POST.get('submit') == 'Edit':
        make_edit()
    elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'Delete':
        make_deletes()
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

Comment: I don't think this works.  Look at your `request.POST` dictionary.  It will be comprised of something like `{'3': 'example@example.com', 'edit':'Edit'}`.  Just like how you can't reference the email address by getting `'text'` from `request.POST`, you need to provide the name of the input button to get their values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using class based views: use this mixin in both your CreateView and UpdateView

```
class CreateOrUpdateViewMixin:

    def form_valid(self, form):

        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if "_save_as_new" in self.request.POST:
            instance.pk = None
        # Next row is optional
        instance.slug = instance._generate_unique_slug 
        self.object = instance
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And write your form as follows:

```
<form
    action="{{ instance.get_update_url }}"
    method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button
        type="submit">
        {% trans "Update the instance" %}
    </button>
    <button
        type="submit"
        name="_save_as_new">
        {% trans "Save as new" %}
    </button>
</form>
```

Credits to @Rushing_tadpole for suggesting using class based views.